# PHP multidimensinal array processing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to ask, how can I process multi-dimensional arrays sent by AJAX to PHP file and then compare them with the database.
I searched a lot but I can`t find a quite good solution. 
The thing is that the array contains the question id of 10 of them and the selected answer for the questions. 
Down below is the code if it helps. Thanks in advance.

```
$("#next_step").click(function() {
    var object = {};
    $("ul.question").each(function() {
        var prasanje = $(this).attr("questionid");
        var odgovor = $("ul#prasanje_" +prasanje+ " > label.answer > li.answer > input.answer:checked").val();
        object[prasanje] = odgovor;
    });
    console.log(object);
    $.ajax ({
        method: "POST",
        url: "procesi.php",
        data: {proces: "proverka_odgovor", data: object},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data < 8) {
                var rezultat = 10 - data;
                $("#error_box").show();
                $(".info_text").html("Имате [" +rezultat+"] грешни прашања. Потребно е да имате миниум 8 точни прашања за да продолжите на втор степен на регистрацијата!");
            } else {
                $("#first_step_box").hide();
                $("#second_step_box").show();
            }
        }
    });
});



 if($_POST["proces"] == "proverka_odgovor") {
    $rezultat = 0;
    $niza_glavna = json_encode($_POST["data"]);
    $data = json_decode($niza_glavna, TRUE);
    foreach ($data as $kviz) {
        $prasanje = $kviz[0];
        $odgovor = $kviz[1];
        $proverka = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM prasanja WHERE id = '$prasanje' AND tocenodgovor = '$odgovor'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($proverka) > 0) {
            $rezultat++;
        }
    }
    echo $rezultat;
}
```

This is what gets sent by ajax. How can I process this array

```
{3: "1", 4: "1", 8: "1", 9: "1", 10: "1", 13: "1", 15: "1", 16: "1", 23: "1", 26: "1"}
```

Comment: Pass the object as JSON and use `json_decode($json, true)` on the server side.

Comment: If you provide a sample of the data being POSTed that will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: why do you need to encode then decode? if you get it as a json string, just decode it alone, after that its just a simple flat array

Comment: In your PHP, add `var_dump($_POST)` just before the `if` statement, or just inside the `if` statement - then add the results to this question.  Otherwise, it's not clear what's happening between your jQuery and your PHP.  (Note: you've said "how can I process this array", but provided a _javascript object_ - we need to see what is being received by _PHP_ in order to provide answers to the question you are asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with a simple array, being sent as JSON. You want to decode it and go from there.

```
$data = json_decode($niza_glavna, TRUE);

$ids = array_keys($data);
$vals = array_values($data);
```

The above fetches the keys and the values in separate arrays, which you can simply run in the query as such:

```
$proverka = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM prasanja WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ") AND tocenodgovor IN (" . implode(',', $vals) . ")");
```

This eliminates the need for any loops and multiple queries.

Comment: In my experience, passing an object as `data` via jQuery results in jQuery turning it into key-value pairs in the `$_POST`... it doesn't appear to me OP has demonstrated _what_ is being received via AJAX.

Comment: @cale_b agreed, answer is based primarily on the data OP has supplied in his updates, it also seems the JSON he's posted isn't valid..Seems he's doing some interesting things